# Multi Publisher

Tags: quarkus, mutiny

First time using a Multi and I am doing something wrong. I want to use a SubmissionPublisher from java.util.concurrent. It implements the Flow.Publisher interface.

```
final SubmissionPublisher<String> subPub1 = new SubmissionPublisher<>();
final var m1 = Multi.createFrom().publisher(subPub1);
```

Multi.createFrom.publishers's signature says the argument needs to implement Flow.Publisher. However, I get a type error.

```
The method publisher(Publisher<T>) in the type MultiCreate is not applicable for the arguments (SubmissionPublisher<String>)
```

I've tried casting it two different ways:

```
final var m1 = Multi.createFrom().publisher((java.util.concurrent.Flow.Publisher<String>) subPub1);
```

and

```
final var m1 = Multi.createFrom().publisher((Publisher<String>) subPub1);
```

but I still get the error:

```
The method publisher(Publisher<T>) in the type MultiCreate is not applicable for the arguments (Flow.Publisher<String>)
```

Any insghts into what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Mutiny 1.x is based on Reactive Streams (predating Flow). Mutiny 2.x switches to Flow as base. Mutiny 2.x will be shipped with Quarkus 3.x; however, there are already usable releases.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `org.reactivestreams.FlowAdapters`;

```java
var flowPublisher = new SubmissionPublisher<String>();
var multi = Multi.createFrom().publisher(FlowAdapters.toPublisher(flowPublisher));
```